# SQLite can't find column of letter strings but can of number strings - E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: (subjectName variable)

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

When the subjectName variable is a string with letters the function doesn't delete the item from the database and throws this error: E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: (subjectName variable)
But when the subjectName variable is a numeric string everything works fine, i dont know why
please help

```
public void deleteLesson(Button buttonLesson) {
    String buttonLessonText = buttonLesson.getText().toString();


    try {

        SQLiteDatabase myDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("LearnUp", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lessons (lesson VARCHAR, year INT(4))");

        Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lessons", null);

        int subjectIndex = c.getColumnIndex("subject");

        int lessonIndex = c.getColumnIndex("lesson");

        c.moveToFirst();
        while (c != null) {
            String tempName = c.getString(subjectIndex);
            if (subjectName.matches(tempName)) {
                Log.i("Info", subjectName+tempName);
                myDatabase.delete("Lessons", "Lesson = ? AND Subject =" + subjectName, new String[] {buttonLessonText});
                
            }

            c.moveToNext();

        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `?` placeholder for `Subject` just like you do for `Lesson`?

Comment: Because I only want to delete columns where subject equals the subjectName variable

Comment: This is what the placeholders do. They are replaced by the values of the variables. Just like the ? from `Lesson = ?` is replaced by the value of the variable `buttonLessonText`.

Comment: It must be said that using the `AND Subject =" + subjectName` style (as opposed to Prepared statement style) is *Really Bad* practise as it enables SQL injection attacks by malicious third parties.

Comment: that fixed it, thank you very much mate